# Python 3.9 open file as binary

Tags: python

I would like to open a file in Python 3.9 in binary format, but it looks like the ASCII signs are not getting interpreted as bytes.

My code:

```
f = open("Unbenannt.png",'rb').read()[0:10]

print(f)
```

I get this output:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00'
```

How do I get it like this?

```
b'\x89\x50\x4e\x47\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 4):

you are confusing representation with the thing being represented... you have bytes

by default a bytestring representation converts printable ascii characters to their printable ascii character

if you want to interpret it as integers from 0-255

```
file_bytes = b'1234567\x119A'
print([b for b in file_bytes])
# [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 17, 57, 65]
```

if you want to have a list of hex strings

```
print([f'{b:02x}' for b in file_bytes])
# ['31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '11', '39', '41']
```

if you want just a single string with \xXX instead of any ascii you can do almost the same

```
print(''.join([f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in file_bytes]))
# '\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x11\x39\x41'
```